# How can I import all files under subdir in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dir structure like this:

```
Proj/
    run.py
    Util/
        __init__.py
        x.py
        y.py
```

In x.py, I define a function:

```
def p():
    return 1
```

In y.py, I define:

```
def q():
    return 2
```

Currently in run.py, I'll use

```
from Util import *
```

But I have to call them using

```
x.p()
y.q()
```

But I want to call them using

```
p()
q()
```

Is there a way that I can do that? Like (as I imagine)

```
from Util.* import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the names up into the package namespace, by using star imports in the `__init__.py`:

```
# in util/__init__.py
from util.x import *
from util.y import *
```

In each submodule, define the names which you want to export by using the `__all__` name:

```
# in x.py
__all__ = ['p']
```

And:

```
# in y.py
__all__ = ['q']
```

This is a pretty standard usage of the `__init__.py` module within a package, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).